# PineScript 1H Strategy Execution Issues

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pinescript strategy running on a 1H timeframe, but it seems to be executing orders incorrectly. I have tried tweaking the (Strat-Properties-Fill Orders) and (Strat-Properties-Recalculate) settings without any headway.

In this example the strategy sells an order at my entry price (expected), but does not stop out like it should and instead shows a win because of it. This leads to bad data, and thus the backtest can't be trusted.

**[1H Chart w/Entry,SL,PT Labelled]**

[image: 1H Chart w/Entry,SL,PT Labelled]

**[1M Chart w/Entry,SL,PT as green lines]**

[image: 1M Chart w/Entry,SL,PT as green lines]

**[10s Chart to show timing better]**

[image: 10s Chart to show timing better]

**[Source Entry/Exit w/variables replaced with values]**

[image: Source Entry/Exit w/variables replaced with values]

**[Setting]**

[image: Setting]

So as you can see, the bar opens and it should have hit my entry price within 20s, then reversed and hit my SL within the next 30s. The strategy however holds until PT like it got in AFTER this fluctuation, or simply ignored the SL hit.

Any help, documentation, or references as to WHY this is happening and/or how to resolve it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you tick _After order is filled_ checkbox? Also, could you please share a minimal reproduciable code so that we can eliminate other factors? Will also need the ticker, timeframe and data information.

Comment: But this is a known issue with backtesting I would say. The emulator is not perfect at intrabar calculations.

Comment: @vitruvius Yeah I played around with all the settings, I posted the real answer below. I understand that the "emulator" is not perfect, but when you pay for a "premium" backtesting platform you expect execution to be a bit better than what I was seeing. I could code up some python in an afternoon that would work better, I just wanted everything in one platform chart/indicators/strat.. but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for answers to this, I found a reference here (https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000669285/) that has this chart:

[image]

Which basically says that on the 1H chart, the bar magnification only digs down into the 10m intrabar data for "granular" execution. Not ideal, but at least it is an answer. Not worth spending the money on "Premium" IMHO at this point.

What I did to actually resolve my problem (somewhat) is just run the backtest on the 1m chart, and calculate the 1hr data I wanted by hand.. cumbersome but at least the executions are MUCH more accurate.